# How do I read the following lines of code?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, nltk-book

Apologies for the basic question as I am quite new to the topic.

```
 conlltags = [(word, pos, chunktag) for ((word,pos),chunktag)
                     in zip(sentence, chunktags))]
```

Can you please break the code above in the format given below:

```
for i in exampleSentence:
    letterByLetter = i
    print(letterByLetter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better for you to look up the following subjects:

- List comprehensions - [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)
- `zip()` function - [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

This will give you a better understanding of what is happening and it is very useful to use in one of your future projects!

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest form I know:

```
conlltags = []
for i in range(min(len(sentence), len(chunktags))):
    conlltags.append((sentence[i][0], sentence[i][1], chunktags[i]))
```